# Set a subset of composite object values using keys from another array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, loops, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I know it has been asked already many times, and I've checked all the other answers - yet still haven't managed to solve my situation, so here goes...

I have a rather complicated structure, due to external constraints (Form, Select inputs, DB API).

I'm receiving input from the user form into my object. One of these elements is a multiple-selection Select-Box, that returns an array of values (days of week). It can return a variable amount of values as an array: a single value or even seven values.

I want to *loop* over these *array values* and use them as *keys* to set the boolean value of my other object.

With this attempt #1, TypeScript doesn't compile and complains that:

```
Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.(2322)
```

With attempt #2, Typescript doesn't compile because:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IDayOfWeek'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IDayOfWeek'.(7053)
```

My intention was first to signal Typescript that these values are all `boolean`. I've tried filtering the keys to only take the boolean ones, but didn't manage, then I tried playing around to implemented some of the ideas I found here, but so far nothing really worked for me or I wasn't able to implement it because of constraints.

In JS it used to be easy - but in Typescript... oh well... ;)

I would appreciate any help,
thanks!

```
// I can't change this:
interface IDayOfWeek {
  sunday?: boolean;
  monday?: boolean;
  tuesday?: boolean;
  wednesday?: boolean;
  thursday?: boolean;
  friday?: boolean;
  saturday?: boolean;
  someOtherValue?: string;
  andAnother?: Date;
}

// I am obligate to use this Select structure:
interface ISelectOption<T> {
    label: string;
    value: T;
}

// I have a limited control of this (React form is mapped to this object with a hook):
interface IUserInput {
  someInputName: string;
  weekday: Array<ISelectOption<keyof IDayOfWeek>>;
}


// and here's where I'm stuck:
function saveUserInput(inp: IUserInput) {
  let dayOfWeek: IDayOfWeek = {};

  // Attempt #1
  for(let key in inp.weekday) {
    dayOfWeek[inp.weekday[key].value] = true;
  }

  // Attempt #2
  for(let key in dayOfWeek) {
      if(inp.weekday.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          dayOfWeek[key] = true;
      }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE4E8DyMDqEEA1sgN4BQyyAzgK4gAm2A-AFzIBGA9twDYQ4IANxVkAW25NWHHv0EixYOhBrMs7LrwFDR1AO4RGIVes1ydi6mAAWdKGplb5usTCjAzs7Qr204ylBezpZ%20NNziEDi20ABqcHwqmjRgHiAA5n5CjACCINwxUJqYkKIAvhQUoJCwiCioAMoQAghgOAAOYMBSADwAKgB85GLUfHCczRwpaZkjyABuCSocfeWV1dDwSGgAqjTQqCDtdGDD1OGR0TZxSxBTqaCzBkTE6hw5UFDYPY3NEK0dLq9YgQLDcGBoTC4AgvAYDNYUGAMVrdED%20eYQPYHI4nAAUoHaHFQWKgh2OYAAlGdkAJTuo8IQSESoQyXsgALzkMqiMQAel5yBg3CguNpyBBWGQoClRwAdIYSOoqZRqPzqMh6TCSABtAnyl7qbUSgC6ssWiQgxo5yFSKj8aoqbmFoogpwlMo12FZJGVc2owBg%20LlCte2FlNjgNBw%20hAAAUoNx2tAwFhcRKKb71Vn1ZrGcQjaCrZzbRA-FmKtQKmUgA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's completely possible to do without changing `IDayOfWeek`.

The problem is that `keyof IDayOfWeek` (in `IUserInput`) isn't specific enough, i.e. we're getting the days of the week which have boolean values, but we're also getting the `someOtherValue`s which aren't booleans. So we don't know if we have the right type when we're assigning the `true`.

The solution is to only use keys that have boolean values, so one option is just manually listing them out:

```
interface IUserInput {
  someInputName: string;
  weekday: Array<ISelectOption<'sunday' | 'monday' | 'tuesday' | 'wednesday' | 'thursday' | 'friday' | 'saturday'>>;
}
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-TADX5NCwLtA7lQRYgvv1e34ZFoUi2jtS8JlNA1SoJFGuinArblCqVQvenywKAcXF4Ah7rE4PD4ggAvMJuro9ANGkgqPpbqAAMQARj0FOoBM0KH4WDYoAo14VADpjfwHEOVWIkaPQIvb9cH-OHABtC82AAXTvUFyiwFIxHHOcBH-LtfxNdhAMvUDwNsYDQCXapbBSXpeiAA)

Another, fancier option is to use a helper type to automatically get the keys that match a boolean value:

```
// Helper to only get the keys that match a particular value.
type FilterKeys<T, U> = NonNullable<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (U | undefined) ? K : never }[keyof T]>;
```

```
interface IUserInput {
  someInputName: string;
  weekday: Array<ISelectOption<FilterKeys<IDayOfWeek, boolean>>>;
}
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEElQYwQwOwOQBdoAt4HMCmomoJYDOAXAFD5xJYBOAZjFDuACIwCeA8rQOpZYDWoAN6lQoQgFc4AE3YB+YqABGAexUAbLPADco0AFsVM+YtUatcXWKQSshWWwXK1mnXoDuWaXDsOnZ10s9PAlqexNnczcxWmp8P1MXCytxGBtqBMjAlMIVfSwOPBoANRh1WydCJDi4DBT4aQBBOBUi6idWKl0AX1JSEAhQGH1QFSV1fAw0nCQVUAlCGYJCUABlLE0oFCrqCS3QrDIKKjoGJnXNpA4AByR8IwAeABUAPmE9MXUYJQ3FHYo6h9QAA3Mq2RRPHp9AYACQ21xouDmRnUbFA2BQRVA-CwbBWeDSBjSUFQQ1A1xg1DuUAkX2oILBWAAdKQkGwEaAAGL4dQnADSuMIzwANKAAKpvAC8oAAckYZbSvuMsA8hKAANp80AUbG4lS0UBPAC6EM1RtAWAAHlQZCsABRi0AAH3mMiwtAoXgAlKA5KAtYofMDEd11Ti2PrDUaXrp+mBIOhg2SJvp8FRpNAjNUNKMDXgiKA7QAlLRbUC0FTUEYF-Qwa4IjOzXDLUZKABWWDL7jTpJgoFQan4XqOlBo9EYEDFi2o4Dg1wkKBEYly+Vn86QMuGh3E1QBKU8Agcika1Go7Ae4Aunaut3ucAe3N5NAFeIvrE4PD4-FFAQsL3-UJxkMMj9jQWAICs7ioGBEAICMVR7PwZC0FIWx3qkwZTjQa4LnaFDXIo4BYTOc4Lj6S6gJoKAOFwvACIR760V+oDSkI3SxmIAyNEgVD6LcoAAMQAIx6BW1B2lRupojq+FMge-AOORQKSYI0qyfJDhhriRpMqC5RYCkYg0Z+AjqupX6aeGOl6bY5rStUtgpL0vRAA)

Comment: This is exactly what I was after! When I tried something similar - it complained because it tried to set a value to a type of 'never'. I think it's your addition of NonNullable that fixes that part. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, there was definitely some fiddling I had to do with the helper type, not the most readable code. NP

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to patch things up to work the way I think you intend them to work, see the code below or [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEElQYwQwOwOQBdoAt4HMCmomoJYDOAXAFD5xJYBOAZjFDuACIwCeA8rQOpZYDWoAN6lQoQgFc4AE3YB%20YqABGAexUAbLPADco0AFsVM%20YtUatcXWKQSshWWwXK1mnXoDuWaXDsOnZ10s9PAlqexNnczcxWmp8P1MXCytxGBtqBMjAlJBxFX0sDjwaADUYdVsnQiQ4uAwcsHhpAEE4FWLqJ1YqXQBfUlJcyBh9UBUldXwMNJwkFVAJQlmCQlAAZSxNKBRq6glt0KwyCio6BiYNraQOAAckfCMAHgAVAD5hPXUYJU3FXYp6noAG7lWyKZ59AZDUDoIE4GCgSb6fBUaTQIw1DRjWi4FagAAUACUtNtQLQVNRRkQDDAbjcvLh5nhqeMAFZYUnuFGoUAI1BqfgASmOlBo9EYEAAqktqOA4DcJCgRGJCPksHKFUgAHIjI7iGoAlKeAQORTgS4c653B5wR78LBsFQ4ljsLi8ASvADaAF1IQNaFJtjbUnDpTQNYr8RQbmaw7L5YrBR8xJoUA43Xx%20GbWJweJnQABeYS9XR6cnUAlQIzVUD2tjY0DRgB0xv4DiTyrEoHTeYEnrrTZBFSw3sLuD2WBS-V6QA).

The only thing that doesn't work is having `someOtherValue` and `andAnother` in the `IDayOfWeek` interface because they are not of type boolean so trying to assign a boolean to either of them results in a type error.

Other than that with a few tweaks from your code things compile

```
interface IDayOfWeek {
  sunday?: boolean;
  monday?: boolean;
  tuesday?: boolean;
  wednesday?: boolean;
  thursday?: boolean;
  friday?: boolean;
  saturday?: boolean;

  // These ⬇ won't work if you're assigning boolean values ❌
  // someOtherValue?: string;
  // andAnother?: Date;
}

interface ISelectOption<T> {
  label: string;
  value: T;
}

interface IUserInput {
  someInputName: string;
  weekday: ISelectOption<keyof IDayOfWeek>[]; // Note the use of keyof, not typeof
}


function saveUserInput(inp: IUserInput) {
  let dayOfWeek: IDayOfWeek = {};

  // This works ✅ as long as IDayOfWeek doesn't have any keys with non-boolean values!
  for (const key of inp.weekday) {
    dayOfWeek[key.value] = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am aware of that :) but unfortunately, I can't change that part. It comes from an external source.

Comment: Why are you trying to assign boolean values to non-boolean fields?